# PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver is not returning what expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to read a lot of .csv files in just one step on Spring Batch with MultiResourceItemReader.As im creating those .csv files in a previous step, I want to tell the MultiResourceItemReader dinamically the path of those files. This is the reader, and the argument **filename** should be the Resource[] that the reader needs.

```
@StepScope
    @Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<MetricsCsv> multiResourceItemReader(
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['inputFiles']}") Resource[] filename
    ){
        MultiResourceItemReader<MetricsCsv> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
        resourceItemReader.setResources(filename);
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate(metricsCsvFlatFileItemReader());
        return resourceItemReader;

    }
```

The stepExecutionContext['inputFiles'] is filled in a previous @BeforeStep:

```
@Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        Resource[] resources = null;
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        try {
            resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:output/temp/*.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("inputFiles",resources);
    }
```

The data is being bound correctly, I can access to it on the multiResourceItemReader method,but looks like the PathMathchingResourcePatternResolver is not returning the files that I'm looking for.

The WARNING that I'm getting is this:

**2022-03-28 16:21:51.862  WARN 19024 --- [           main] o.s.b.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader  : No resources to read. Set strict=true if this should be an error condition.**

I know it's a warning and not an error, but why would the resolver not return my *.csv files?

[Those are the directories of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wUvj.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to resolve files with their absolute path and not relative to the classpath?

Comment: I got the same output with that solution, thanks.